# Map<String,String> Key Value on Postman

Tags: java, api, controller, postman

I am currently build a controller that will accept an parameter with Map i need to pass it through form-data because of Multipart File. I cannot pass a Map on postman, it keeps giving me this error

```
"Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Map for property variables; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Map for property variables: no matching editors or conversion strategy found"
```

This is what i currently pass on PostMan

Key

```
variables
```

Value

```
variables : {"abc": "123"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to deserialize that string.
Maybe you want to take a look at something like GSON to convert that JSON string into your Java `Map<String, String>`
https://github.com/google/gson

It should be something like this:

```
    String someJSONMap = "{\"abc\":\"123\"}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType();
    Map<String,String> result = gson.fromJson(someJSONMap, type);
```